# Need a formula to determine the maximum number of days between multiple consecutive dates

Tags: excel, date, max, difference

I have a string of consecutive dates in an excel table that represent when items were picked up from a store.  I need to determine either if any gap is more than 60 days or the greatest gap.  Example:

9/5/18, 9/18/19, 11/20/18, 12/21/18

The gap between the 2nd and third dates is the greatest at 63.  I either need the "63" or a "yes" if >63.  I have a few hundred rows of these dates so looking for a formula without the need to build helper tables.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are these all in the same cell, or different cells?

Comment: Perhaps use a simple formula to calculate the gaps, and then a conditional format rule to highlight the biggest one and/or the ones bigger than 60? I think that would be the simplest solution to implement.

Answer (score 1):

IF the dates are in different cells:

```
=MAX(B1:D1-A1:C1)>60
```

Depending on one's version this may need to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

[image]

---

If they are in the same cell, comma delimited:

```
=MAX(FILTERXML("<a><b>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1,",","</b><b>")&"</b></a>","//b["&ROW($ZZ$2:INDEX($ZZ:$ZZ,LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,",",""))+1))&"]")-FILTERXML("<a><b>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1,",","</b><b>")&"</b></a>","//b["&ROW($ZZ$1:INDEX($ZZ:$ZZ,LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,",",""))))&"]"))>60
```

Depending on one's version this may need to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

[image]

Comment: ... even included a FILTERXML approach, awesome, upvoted.

Answer (score 1):

If the dates are all in a single cell, and you have a recent version of Excel with the `SEQUENCE` function, you can use:

```
=AGGREGATE( 14,6,DATEVALUE(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1,",",REPT(" ",99)),SEQUENCE(10)*99,99)))-DATEVALUE(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1,",",REPT(" ",99)),IF(SEQUENCE(10)=1,1,(SEQUENCE(10)-1)*99),99))),1)
```

where the `10` argument for `SEQUENCE` is just some value greater than the total possible number of included entries.

If you do not have the `SEQUENCE` function, you can use something like:

```
=ROW(INDEX($A:$A,1,1):INDEX($A:$A,255,1))
```

I prefer to make that a named formula, and name it `seq`, so the final formula would look like:

```
=AGGREGATE( 14,6,DATEVALUE(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A3,",",REPT(" ",99)),seq*99,99)))-DATEVALUE(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A3,",",REPT(" ",99)),IF(seq=1,1,(seq-1)*99),99))),1)
```

Comment: If one does not have `SEQUENCE` replace all the `SEQUENCE(10)` with `row($ZZ$1:$ZZ$10)`

Comment: @ScottCraner I don't like that construct. Although simple, it is sensitive to row insertions/deletions.  For example, insert a row at row 1, and the sequence starts with a `2`.  I prefer the more complex but robust `row(index($a:$a,1,1):index($a:$a,255,1))`

Answer (score 0):

Date-Times in excel are in days since the epoch, floating point, with a presentation number format that you can adjust (I like YYYY-MM-DD iso date).  It should be easy to convert your strings to dates, if they are not already dates by automatic conversion.  I bet there is a function for that!  Subtract them, but since the are date-time floating point numbers with fractions, you might need to find a function named int or integer to scrape off any fraction.  Of course, if they all lack time components, that part defaults to the same time, so the subtraction returns whole days.

Comment: This is good information, but I'm not sure it actually answers the question.

Comment: =a3-a2 yanked down b from b3 is days between dates in a?